# How to make trigger that will disable delete on particular table in SQLite?

Tags: django, sqlite

How to make trigger that will disable delete on particular table in SQLite ?
So that new rows can be added, but you can not delete already adder rows.

I am having trouble with syntax.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER nodel_booksInventory_booklanguage DELETE on booklanguage
BEGIN
    RAISE ( ABORT, "MY ERROR") 
END
```

But it is not working.
I am adding it via booklanguage.sqlite3.sql SQL file with manage.py syncdb in Django.

Comment: Just go through the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html). With what particular part do you have a problem?

Comment: @CL I have added explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), you can use only UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT/SELECT statements in a trigger body.

To use the RAISE function, wrap it inside a SELECT:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER nodel_booksInventory_booklanguage
BEFORE DELETE ON booklanguage
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'my error');
END;
```

Comment: There are some problems in implement this in Django, so I can not verify is this correct. Anyway for you effort I will accept it.